# Duplicate Requests only in some networks

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application running on a client-server (W2016, .NET 4.5). When I access one of the pages on their server from our office, the page gets hit once. Inspecting the IIS logs (`%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2`) show a GET for that page, then I push a button on the page and the log file shows a POST. This seems to be working fine so far.

Now when I remote into the client's network and access the page from one of their local machines, the log file shows a GET, then I push the button on the page and the log shows two POSTs at the same second. The first one shows status (`sc-status, sc-substatus, sc-win32-status`) **200 0 64**, the second shows **200 0 0**. 
In the log file, both POSTs are identical. Basically the log looks like this (except I masked some of the data):

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status 
2009-08-11 20:19:32 x.x.x.x GET /File.aspx - 80 - y.y.y.y Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+MDDR;+OfficeLiveConnector.1.4;+OfficeLivePatch.0.0) 200 0 0
2009-08-11 20:19:45 x.x.x.x POST /File.aspx - 80 - y.y.y.y Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+MDDR;+OfficeLiveConnector.1.4;+OfficeLivePatch.0.0) 200 0 64
2009-08-11 20:19:45 x.x.x.x POST /File.aspx - 80 - y.y.y.y Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.0;+WOW64;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC1;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.21022;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30618;+MDDR;+OfficeLiveConnector.1.4;+OfficeLivePatch.0.0) 200 0 0
```

The problem is, the page is getting hit twice. The database performs an operation for the first request, then the second request detects that a duplicate operation is being performed and throws an error message. The users think their operation failed, but it actually succeeded.

I tried to find common things like Browser, OS, Firewall and ... but they had not anythings.

**Update**: It only occurs when SSL enabled.

Comment: Did you check the protocol? (http or https?) I think IIS redirector can cause the issue

Comment: Yes, I checked. Why IIS Redirector and how can I handle that?

Comment: Browse your app with Chrome. Open its developer's console and then look at its network tab. Here select "preserve log" option. And then try to run that page again. after that, post the image of your output (network tab) here. Also `AutoEventWireup` can cause your issue (https://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/17/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx) or even an empty image (http://geekswithblogs.net/bcaraway/archive/2007/08/24/114945.aspx).

Comment: Note:It only occurs when SSL enabled

Comment: If client request in http protocol and not https and IIS is configured to redirect http requests to https, can cause the issue.

Comment: @EhsanMajdabadi: only https binding is available. and only https url authorized in network

Comment: Do you have some sort of fire wall (WAF) in your client network? If that is so, 99% I am sure it is the cause !

Comment: @Rathma: I tested without WAF...same results!